# Display a Devexpress UseControl as a Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How do you display a custom DevExpress UserControl as a dialog in C#/Winforms (.NET 3.5 or higher)?
I dont' see a usercontrol1.ShowDialog(). I could use a devexpress memoedit, winforms Button.

Thanks

Comment: You need to make a form.  (you may want to make an `XtraForm`)

Comment: Thanks. Any examples?

Comment: What do you need an example for? Make a form. Put your usercontrol in the form. Show the form.

Comment: cool thanks, I guess in DevExpress.XtraEditors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-Click on Projekt -> Add -> New Element -> DevExpress Form

On this Form you can add your control. Call `myForm.ShowDialog()` method and you have a dialog.